# Android GPUImage Library

Tags: java, android, bitmap, gpuimage

In iOS, I am calling this filter function to get the image result.

`UIImage filteredImage = [[[GPUImageAmatorkaFilter alloc] init] imageByFilteringImage:imgOriginal];`

The return is `UIImage`, so is straight forward but in Android the return is not `bitmap`.

So, how can I get the filtered `bitmap`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a UIImage isn't a bitmap either. What data type does the Android port of GPUImage return? That will help people to say how to get a bitmap out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Android you can use [Android-GPUImage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)

Answer (score 0):

For obtain the bitmap in android with GPUImage Library there are two methods.

You can set the image file and request the bitmap filtered:

```
    GPUImage mGPUImage = new GPUImage(this);
    mGPUImage.setImage(mImage);
    mGPUImage.setFilter(mGPUImageFilter);
    mGPUImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();
```

mImage can be:

`Uri mImage
 File mImage
 Bitmap mImage`

or you can filter the bitmap directly:

```
    GPUImage mGPUImage = new GPUImage(this);
    mGPUImage.setFilter(mGPUImageFilter);
    Bitmap bitmapFiltered = mGPUImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied(bitmapToFilter);
```